# Element having css style with transform: translate animation

Tags: html, css

If I apply animation to element having css style with transform: translate
for example

```
transform: translateY(100px);
```

at the end of animation the element jumps to desired position. How to avoid this jump and get smooth animation to desired position?

http://jsfiddle.net/alexchetv/bc49LnLt/

Comment: You should end your animation with this value if you don't want the sudden jump but do want it to end up at that point. If you want the animations ending value to be more important and applied, use something like `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to accomplish that.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the last *keyframe*:

```
to {
  transform: none;
}
```

```css
div {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#f00;
    animation:bounceInDown 1s;
    transform: translateY(100px);
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem on Opera and Chrome, It's a sneaky bug in Webkit. However, hope these two lines would help.

```
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-out;
```